# highlighting previous row after ng-click

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdownlist which contains brand ids. acccording to the id im fetching corresponding products and showing it in a table. There are two buttons in each row that move the products up and down basically by interchanging the ranks. now i am able to do all the functionality of interchanging and re binding.The row is selected when it is clicked. my only problem is i am not able to select the row after it has moved up or down.

```
             <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="prodctrl">
               <select id="BrandDropdown" class="InstanceList" ng-change="GetBrandProd()" ng-model="Products">

               <option>Select Brand</option>    //Sample Data
               <option value=1>Brand 1<option>
               <option value=2>Brand 2<option>

             </select>
       <table id="prodtab" ng-model="Products">
         <tr ng-repeat="P in Products track by $index" ng-click="setselected($index)" class="{{selected}}">
            <td>{{P.Id}}</td>
            <td>{{P.Rank}}</td>
            <td>{{P.Name}}</td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Move Up" id="moveup" ng-click="getval(P,$index)" /></td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Move Down" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

this is the angularjs code

```
           <script>
         var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
        var prod = null;
      var mveup = null;
      var mvedwn = null;
         var ind = null;
         app.controller('prodctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            //getting products for each brand
           $scope.GetBrandProd = function () {
         cursel = "B";
         var Id = $('#BrandDropdown').val();
           fetchtype = Id;
          brid = Id;
              $http({
              method: "GET",
              url: "/Home/GetProdBrand",
              params: {
                  id: Id
                      }


                     })
                 .success(function (response) {
                  var data = response;
                     $scope.Products = data;
                 prod = data;
                   });

                       };

              //changing color of row when clicked
            $scope.setselected = function (index) {

               if ($scope.lastSelected) {
                  $scope.lastSelected.selected = '';
                  }
                if (mveup == null) {
                this.selected = 'trselected';
                 $scope.lastSelected = this;
                }
              else {
                 mveup = null;
               //this.selected = '';
                 $(this).closest('tr').prev().prop('Class', 'trselected');

                  }



              };
               //function to move product up in ranking
             $scope.getval = function (p, index) {
             var Idcur = p.Id;
             var Rankcur = p.Rank;
             ind = index;
              if ($scope.Products[index - 1] != null) {
                var IdPrev=$scope.Products[index - 1].Id;
                var Rankprev = $scope.Products[index - 1].Rank;

               mveup = null;
                $scope.lastSelected = this;

               if (cursel == "B") {

                fetchtype = brid;
                 }
                 else if (cursel == "C") {
                 }
                  mveup = true;
               $http({
                 method: "GET",
                 url: "/Home/MoveProd",
                   params: {
                      Curid: Idcur,
                      CurRank: Rankcur,
                      ChngId: IdPrev,
                      ChngRnk: Rankprev,
                      Type: cursel,
                      Id: fetchtype
                  }


               })
               .success(function (response) {
               // ranks are interchanged and the data is returned.
                   var data = response;
                   $scope.Products = data;
                   prod = data;




               });
           }
       }

    })
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, the way you are handling the row selection is not correct.

I have just changed the way of handling selection here.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="P in Products track by $index" ng-click="setselected($index)" ng-class="{selected: selectedIndex == $index}">
```

//JS

```
  $scope.setselected = function(index) {
    $scope.selectedIndex = index;
  };
```

Also, I have done a plunker with some sample values to imitate your requirement, you can ask more, if it is not fit to your requirement.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2J82pHZ3E1BqQPn28MR6?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You already have the id of the product that was clicked on (I think from looking at your code, it's `Idcur`), so you could loop over your results in the `success`  block of the `/Home/MoveProd` GET request and set the record with the matching id to selected? Something like

```
var products = $scope.Products.filter(function(product) {
   return product.id == Idcur;
})

if (products && products.length > 0) {
    products[0].selected = 'trselected';
}
```

then, in your page, just update the ng-repeat slightly to pick the `selected` class from the product, instead of the scope, so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="P in Products track by $index" ng-click="setselected($index)" class="{{selected}}">
```

becomes

```
<tr ng-repeat="P in Products track by $index" ng-click="setselected($index)" class="{{P.selected}}">
```

or something like that :)